# How to check a null value of the Cursor?

Tags: android, android-cursor, isnull

I need to check whether the column value is null. The [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29): `isNull returns TRUE if the value in the indicated column is null.` So, I'm trying to implement this in the code:

```
if (c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex("description")))
            description.setText("The column is null");
        else
            description.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")));
```

But even if the column is empty, I don't get `true` in the condition. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe when the column is empty, it returns an empty string. An empty string will return `false` when you check with `c.isNull()`.

Comment: Null isn't the same as "empty".

Comment: No. Null is the value `null`, an empty string is `""`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel , the column in the table contains `null`. There's no empty string.

Comment: @MarkKorzhov Well, either you have a defective phone/tablet/device/emulator or you are writing `"null"` in it. Or it isn't returning `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = c.getColumnIndex("description");
String str = c.getString(index);
if (str == null || str.isEmpty() || str.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
    description.setText("Empty!");
} else {
    description.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: I do not need to check for the existence of the column - I need to check its value.

Comment: @MarkKorzhov do: `Log.e("TAG", "This is: "+c.getString(index));` what do you get? Also updated my answer, and if this works for you, it's pretty ridiculous :)

Comment: `if (str.equals("null"))` - thanks for advice, it works!

Comment: Works for me. Thank you very much! @user3249477 Please , do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/pcR95K

Answer (score -1):

```
getColumnIndex(String columnName)
```

Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.

When your column is empty the getColumnIndex(String columnName) returns -1, and isNull with -1 is not true